# XML Spec: Union of xs:date, xs:gYearMonth, xs:gYear?

Tags: xml, types, specifications, xml-validation

I'm working with an XML spec and it defines a "type" 'date' that is:

> date: A union of xs:date, xs:gYearMonth, xs:gYear

Where the above datatypes are from [W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) 1.1 Part 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#boolean)

My question is, does that mean I can expect the `date` value to possibly be:

1. Comma separated instances of those W3C types? (eg `<date value="xs:date, xs:gYear"/>`)
2. Or, more simply that date's value could be in any of those formats?
3. Or, either 1. or 2.?

Essentially, I'm looking for more clarification on what **"A union of"** means in this context.

Comment: Instead of an explanation, show us the code, i.e. the definition of that type.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - I just noticed you comment and although I think it's generally valid (ie your XY problem) the issue I had was that the specification itself was incomplete. *In some instances*, providing code can actually be less indicative of the issue.

Comment: No, that's not an XY problem - it is not as if your actual problem was hidden from us. But  `date: A union of xs:date, xs:gYearMonth, xs:gYear` does not tell us what the XSD code actually looks like; it's just a description, after all. The code might or might not be a straightforward `xs:union` of predefined types. SO experience tells you to never rely on descriptions and explanations when there could be code. But I really should have written _in addition_, not _instead_. By the way: please be careful with terminology; "specification" is an authoritative standard, not an XSD document.

Comment: For your future questions about XML Schema, a perfect question contains: a complete, minimal XSD document, minimal instances of XML documents that are valid or invalid with regard to this XSD _and_ a description of your problem. That way, you will get better anwers more quickly.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - I indeed was working with a *specification*. One that enables you to build an XSD document based on several type definitions that are provided (but not the primary goal of the spec.) Your comments describe my issue *exactly* - "code might or might not be a straightforward xs:union of predefined types". It is still entirely unclear to me whether or not I'm correctly adhering to the author's vision of `xs:union` but I'm going to assume *most* people are adhering to the accepted answer's interpretation, and just ear mark that area as a possible issue.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - in other words, in order to provide you with a sample XSD and XML, I would have needed to create it based on the incomplete information in this post - which, in my opinion, wouldnt have been useful at all. Thank you for your constructive feedback, however, I could have been clearer about what exactly I was asking.

Comment: I see. Your question is a bit misleading because one might think that you already have XSD code, whereas you are really asking about how to write it. You were right about the XY problem :-). At any rate, kjughes' interpretation is the most sensible one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Union" here is in the set theoretical sense.

So, any value that satisfies the constraints of `xs:date` or `xs:gYearMonth` or `xs:gYear` will be valid.  In other words, a full date, just the year and month, or just the year are acceptable.

See the date/time [Seven-Property Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#theSevenPropertyModel) and [Lexical Mappings](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#rf-lexicalMappings-datetime) for  details.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without more context, but it's quite likely that this means that the type can either be an `xs:date`, `xs:gYearMonth`, or `xs:gYear`, taking whichever comes first.

It's unlikely that it would mean CSV.